# Is the following statement: $\frac{1}{1+O(T)} = 1+ {O(T)}$ true?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Is the following statement:

$\dfrac{1}{1+O(T)} = 1+ {O(T)}$

true, and if so,  why?

Comment: You should precise it is in $0$.

Comment: It is as $T \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{1+x}=1+O(x),$$

therefore $$\frac{1}{1+O(x)}=1+O(x).$$